# Is shownig the data as javascript using the echo dangerous?

Tags: javascript, php

Consider we have a `login.php` file as follows:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// check fields and if they were correct and they are  secure against injection attacks anf if there was the username and password
echo '<script> javascript code </script>';
?>
```

Can the hackers attack to the simple `php` code using the `XSS` attack?

Comment: Google those keywords.

Comment: you cannot echo script inside php

Comment: If you want to pass data between _php_ and _JavaScript_ then use _JSON_, even if it's the generated source.

Comment: You need to explain what you plan to place in the javascript code. Do you plan to put the username and password there? If so, it will be part of the text of the HTML document. Are you sending this over plain text? If so, everyone can see it. As for syed's comment "you cannot echo script inside php" - that is so wrong it can only be a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no differents between showing javascript/html by using php echo or just a plain html file.
2. XSS is a risk in your example, if you place direct form input (like the post) in the  'echo':

WRONG:
`echo '<script> javascript '.$_POST['username'].' code </script>';`

BETTER:
`echo '<script> javascript '.aEscapeFuntion($_POST['username']).' code </script>';`

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414962/protection-against-xss-exploits) for more information about building your 'aEscapeFunction'.